# How to configure Spring Cloud Sleuth in Spring Boot microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

Can someone please help me? I want to integrate Spring Sleuth with my Spring Boot microservices. I added `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` dependency. Also tried by added SLF4J along with it. But it is print normal logs. Not printing in Sleuth style like app name, span id ,traceid etc. I am not sure if it is recognizing dependency? Do I need to add any other dependency? Any properties file?

Could you please guide with exact dependency? and exact steps to configure?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of logging, we support `slf4j` out of the box. You have to implement your own `SpanLogger interface` to add the logging support for `log4j`

Comment: I am ok to go without Log4j. I have removed all those dependencies and added spring-sleuth dependency. But i don't see any effect in logs. (still the logs are not the way they are supposed to be with spring sleuth). Please help.

Comment: Please post your sample somewhere. Without this I can only guess what's wrong. Here you have a working example https://github.com/openzipkin/sleuth-webmvc-example